# AngularJS two way binding variables to array items

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, two-way

To view my code follow this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Snsa90/br270sdj/1/)

I've created a directive which handles an array of items (it will always be two because it's a "from" and "to" date pair).

I want to make the array items accessible as separate values for later use so I refer to the array items like this

```
  vm.data = ['data a', 'data b'];
  vm.separateData = vm.data[0];
  vm.otherData = vm.data[1];
```

When I implement a two way bind into the directive, the `vm.data[0]` and `vm.data[1]` references are updated but the `vm.separateData` and `vm.otherData` aren't.

Is there a way of making this work or should I just restructure the rest of my app (where needed) to accomodate for array items?

In my fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Snsa90/br270sdj/1/) (same as above) try changing the text input values and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: really not getting your question

Comment: open the fiddle and try changing the text input variable, you'll see what I mean, I really don't know how to make it clearer without writing a novel here - sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vm.data[0] is a string and thus it is a primitive datatype in javascript which is immutable. So you bind the immutable String 'Data a' to vm.separateData, which is not a reference to data[0].

If you want to copy the reference to the array into vm.separateData try to wrap your strings in other javascript objects, e.g.

```
vm.data = [{"value":"Data a"}, {"value":"Data b"}]
```

and then you can reference

```
vm.separateData = vm.data[0];
```

and access the value via

```
vm.separateData.value
```

Comment: valid point thanks! but it seems it's not quite working - have a look https://jsfiddle.net/Snsa90/gyf3dexa/1/ ... have I misinterpreted you ?

Comment: maybe i should just restructure the queries i have in the rest of the app to take data[0] instead of variable values, that way it would work - i was just wondering is there a less risky workaround...

Comment: You now still copy the immutable string, as you use data[0].value. Look here :https://jsfiddle.net/hn08wuhL/